# NetOffice add-in not loading with 64 bit Office 2013 installation

Tags: c#, netoffice

I have build a Multi add-in using NetOffice it working fine allover expect on 64 bit installation of Office. Anyone have idea about this all registry entry is going at correct place, still it is showing in Inactive Add-in list with empty path(see attached image)
[image: Location is empty]

Comment: 64-bit versions will only load 64-bit addins. Did you compile for 64-bit?

Comment: I compile it for Any CPU & it should word as mentioned in NetOffice documentation.

Comment: Actually, the documentation says that you have to compile for 64 bit `If you develop a COMAddin that is being used by a 64Bit Office application, you have to compile your assembly as x64.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to compile your add-in for 64-bit. Native applications like Office can't load dlls for different architectures. This is actually mentioned in the NetOffice documentation, in the section *Is NetOffice ready for multiple platforms(32/64 Bit)?*:

> If you develop a COMAddin that is being used by a 64Bit Office application, you have to compile your assembly as x64. If you wart to support 32Bit and 64Bit Office applications, you may need to provide a second x64-compiled COMAddin. This behaviour is the same in all scenarios(interop,vsto or netoffice). A 64Bit application can only load 64Bit Dll's.

The `AnyCPU` architecture means that the assembly can be used by *.NET* programs targeting any architecture. It doesn't apply to native programs. `AnyCPU` is treated as a 32-bit dll in COM and interop scenarios

Comment: Thanks Panagiotis for well explained answer, It is working after changing platform target: to x64.